# Суммирование датафреймов Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Всем добрый день!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как при суммировании датафреймов в Pandas суммировать только числовые значения, игнорируя при этом текстовые?

Суммировать диапазонами будет проблемно, так как исходные данные содержат по восемь достаточно объемных таблиц с разными диапазонами числовых ячеек.

Обычное суммирование датафреймов выполняет как раз то, что нужно, особенно если получится избавиться от суммирования текста.

Код:

```
template_adress = glob.glob('template/*')

svod = pd.read_excel(template_adress[0], engine='openpyxl')

for filename in glob.glob('Excel/*'):
    dataframe = pd.read_excel(filename, engine='openpyxl')
    svod = svod + dataframe
    print(f'{dt.datetime.now()}: {filename} добавлен в свод.')

svod.to_excel(f'Svod.xlsx')
print(f'{dt.datetime.now()}: Свод сформирован.')
```

Датафрейм:

```
0          1          1          1
1        NaN        NaN        NaN
2        NaN        NaN        NaN
3  Столбец 1  Столбец 2  Столбец 3
4          1          1          1
5        NaN        NaN        NaN
6        NaN        NaN        NaN
7  Столбец 1  Столбец 2        NaN
8          1          1        NaN
```

Свод, который получается сейчас (суммируются строковые значения):

```
                              Столбец 1                             Столбец 2                             Столбец 3
0                                     7                                     7                                     7
1                                   NaN                                   NaN                                   NaN
2                                   NaN                                   NaN                                   NaN
3  Столбец 1Столбец 1Столбец 1Столбец 1  Столбец 2Столбец 2Столбец 2Столбец 2  Столбец 3Столбец 3Столбец 3Столбец 3
4                                     7                                     7                                     7
5                                   NaN                                   NaN                                   NaN
6                                   NaN                                   NaN                                   NaN
7  Столбец 1Столбец 1Столбец 1Столбец 1  Столбец 2Столбец 2Столбец 2Столбец 2                                   NaN
8                                     7                                     7                                   NaN
```

Comment: Получилось сделать через to_numeric, правда теперь в датафреймах снесло все текстовые поля вообще. Разбираюсь дальше.

Comment: а зачем вам текстовые данные внутри результирующей таблицы?

Comment: Чтобы сохранить изначальный вид таблицы. Свод должен быть в форме пригодной для печати и восприятия человеком.

Comment: а вам не кажется, что украшения таблицы для печати и восприятия - немного отдельная задача?

Comment: Согласен. В рамках изначального запроса задача решена. Вопрос закрываю.

Comment: вопрос можно не закрывать. задача есть, решение есть, к оформлению особых вопросов нет. Мало ли, этот вопрос кому-то поможет?

Comment: Да, пусть остается. Я просто указал решение.

Answer (score 0):

Задача решилась с использоваванием `dataframe.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')`